# text & mouse over and mouse out value on bar graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was using d3.js v4 and having difficulty in showing the value on horizontal bar chart and mouse over and mouse out pop to show the desired value from data

please find the below code i have used

```
            var data = [{Issue:"Other",Number:808,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other1",Number:80,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other2",Number:8,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other3",Number:67,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other4",Number:45,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other5",Number:9,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other6",Number:60,Stage:"A"},
{Issue:"Other7",Number:8,Stage:"A"}];


var margin = {top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 400},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select("#barchart" ).append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Number = +d.Number;
  });

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.Number; })])
y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Issue; }));

svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) {return x(d.Number); } )
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Issue); })
.style("fill",function(d) { 
    if(d.Stage=='I')
    return '#3dc778'
    if(d.Stage=='B')
        return '#e52929'
        if(d.Stage=='U')
            return '#3021fd'
            if(d.Stage=='A')
                return '#eefd21'
 })
.attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

How can we   text to each bar and mouse hover and mouse out functionality for the above code snippet?

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated per request:

```js
var data = [{
    Issue: "Other",
    Number: 808,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other1",
    Number: 80,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other2",
    Number: 8,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other3",
    Number: 67,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other4",
    Number: 45,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other5",
    Number: 9,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other6",
    Number: 60,
    Stage: "A"
  },
  {
    Issue: "Other7",
    Number: 8,
    Stage: "A"
  }
];


var margin = {
    top: 15,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 400
  },
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Number = +d.Number;
});

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.Number;
})])
y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Issue;
}));

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'group')
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.Number);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.Issue);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.Stage == 'I')
      return '#3dc778'
    if (d.Stage == 'B')
      return '#e52929'
    if (d.Stage == 'U')
      return '#3021fd'
    if (d.Stage == 'A')
      return '#eefd21'
  })
  .on("mouseover", d => mouseover(d))
  .on("mousemove", mousemove)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

svg.selectAll(".group")
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'count')
  .text(d => d.Number)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.Number) + 5;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.Issue) + y.bandwidth() / 2 + 5;
  })

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

function mouseover(d) {
  div.style("display", "inline");
  div.text(d.Stage)
}

function mousemove() {
  div
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 34) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 12) + "px");
}

function mouseout() {
  div.style("display", "none");
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background: #ddd;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='barchart'></div>
</body>
```

The tooltip was shamelessly stolen from here:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1087001

Comment: Hi Andy can you make changes so that number will be displayed on each graph instead of mouse Hover.on Mouse hover a pop up should get displayed with the "stage" value in data

Comment: @user3349850 Done!

Comment: Hi Andy Pop up is working fine .but number  values are not being displayed on the graph bar .

Comment: @user3349850 Sorry, thought you didn't want the labels at all. They've back (and without hover)